# How can I sync my Resharper settings between computers?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper, settings

I have a work PC and a laptop at home that I dev on using Resharper.  Unfortunately, every time I add a live template or change my formatting settings, I have to export and import the settings/templates between computers.

For visual studios settings, I use the [Automatically save my settings to this file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1x6229t8.aspx) option in conjunction with a file on Dropbox to accomplish this.  Is there an any way to do this with Resharper settings/templates?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For **ReSharper 5** you can use the [ReSharper Settings Manager Plugin](http://rsm.codeplex.com/) which saves all ReSharper settings to a single file. This would usually be used to share settings amongst a team through source control, but you could of course just use the config file it generates to move settings between computers with your Dropbox method. Just ensure you have the plugin installed on each machine. The plugin monitors for config file changes and will automatically update ReSharper settings when it sees a change - no VS restarts necessary.

I discuss automating sharing of ReSharper settings and using this plugin (in a team context) in an article I wrote here:

http://gojisoft.com/blog/2010/05/10/coding-standards-using-resharper/

**Update**

For those that can upgrade to **ReSharper 6.1.1** and above, ReSharper now has built-in support for sharing all settings across teams.

Comment: Awesome, this is what I was looking for.  Do you know if there is any way to have the plug-in automatically save/load settings.  It seems like if you change Resharper settings, you have to go under Manage Settings and manually save/load them.

Comment: @JChristian In my experience once you have set the association up, you do not have to manually load the settings, but you do have to save them manually when you make a change. There does appear to be some mention of automatically saving settings in the latest release, but I have not used it and am not sure how far it goes.

Comment: You are right.  You have to manually save, but it does load changes automatically.  I was trying to update settings with visual studio open on the other PC.  In this case you have to restart VS or load the settings manual.  Not a big deal in my case, though, as I can't see this happening often.